# VS2019 MVC Database solution won't work on a second machine

Tags: sql-server, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2019

I had created a webpage with DB access which works perfectly well on the machine I develop it. However, when I copy everything across to another machine, it fails with an error message - cannot open database xxx requested by the login. I did copy everything including the database created in the development environment and put it in the same place as the development did. What other thing I had done wrong ? Please help. **In addition, when I open the solution on another machine, I cannot see the database from the SQL Server Object Explorer like what I saw on the development machine.**

Comment: What is the actual authentication error when you look at the SQL Server's logs? Sounds like the `LOGIN` exists, but the `USER`, or a `USER` mapped to the `LOGIN` does not.

Comment: It said the database failed to open by [pc name]/[username] where this pair is different from the development PC. I had set the database to use window authentication to open. So the issue can be authentication failure or the database is not found. However, how to explain when I open the solution in VS on the other machine, the database is not found in the SQL Server Object Explorer ? This point to the fact that the database is not found at all.

Comment: Error Message :-
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query: Error: An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'CenterInfo.Data.CenterInfoContext'.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "CenterInfoContext-b006176f-548f-4eb2-841e-752dca8817f0" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'LAPTOP-KKIHRDME\Sum'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
ClientConnectionId:956802c2-9577-4750-8c92-a4845eecbd42
Error Number:4060,State:1,Class:11

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved ! Need to copy the database and the log file across and the used the SQL Server Manager to attach the database to the right server. After that, everything just work !!